# Pass in username and password in an xml request to wcf service for authentication?

Tags: xml, wcf

I have a wcf service in which the user will need to be authenticated before they can make a service call.  There will be no website where the user is validated through login or a windows/console app where the user is validated.  I was thinking of doing something like this:

Pass in a request:

```
<GetCars>
    <Credentials username="test" password="test" />
</GetCars>
```

If the username and password are successful, return the successful response for GetCars else fail.

The problem is that I don't know how to pass in a request to a wcf service like the above and then read the username and password attributes to validate it.

Comment: You might also want to look into WS-Security which has built in authentication handling for WCF SOAP requests.

Comment: I am using wsHttpBinding.  I am unclear on where to put the code when an xml request is sent in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will shortly try to describe the method I use in my own WCF Service for authentication.  There is built-in authentication handling with WCF SOAP endpoints using WS-Security specification (i.e., `wsHttpBinding`, as you are using).  You can implement using settings in web.config like this:

```
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="myBindingName">
      <security mode="Message">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
      </security>
```

Then you can specify a custom type to handle authentication logic:

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="myBehaviorName">
      <serviceCredentials>
        <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="NameSpaceName.Class,AssemblyName" />
      </serviceCredentials>
```

This class that handles authentication logic should extend `UserNamePasswordValidator` (will need to reference `System.IdentityModel.dll` and import `System.IdentityModel.Selectors` for this) and override `Validate`:

```
public class MyValidator : UserNamePasswordValidator {
    public override void Validate(string userName, string password) {
        // check password. if success, do nothing
        // if fail, throw a FaultException
    }
}
```

Calling this code using an ASP.Net WCF client needs to use `ClientCredential` to pass the username and password, like this:

```
// This pattern needs to be repeated and username / password set with every creation
// of a client object.  This can be refactored to a separate method to simplify.
MyAPIClient client = new MyAPIClient();

// yes UserName is there twice on purpose, that's the proper structure
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = theUsername;
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = thePassword;

try {
    client.Open();
    client.DoSomething();
    client.Close();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    // handle exception, which should contain a FaultException;
    // could be failed login, or problem in DoSomething
}
```

Obviously the binding and behavior defined above have to be assigned to the service itself using the `behaviorConfiguration` and `bindingConfiguration` properties.

Comment: I have have everything that you mentioned in the web.config and I have a custom validator, so are you saying that in my Validate should read the username and password from the xml file and set it to UserName and Password for ClientCredentials

Comment: This authentication structure is replacing your idea of parsing it from an XML request.  The `Validate` should contain the logic you intended behind your statement "If the username and password are successful, return the successful response for GetCars else fail."  What is determining if username and password are successful?  That's what should go in `Validate`.

Comment: In my case, the username and password are going to come in from an xml request.  I guess I can use Linq to Xml to read the username and password attributes?

Comment: It is not actually hitting my Validate method.  When I try put GetCars into the url it says Bad Request