# Passing in user credentials without forms login or setting the credentials in a client proxy?

Tags: wcf

This question is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5983605/33690), but I am still unclear how it should work.
The problem, I have is that most examples have the ClientCredentials for the service being set through forms login or setting the username and password through a custom app that accesses the service.  In my case it is a different.  Here is my scenario:

I have a WCF Service that is hosted in an empty website in IIS.  There is no default page, the only thing you can access is the WCF Service, so the question I have is how do I pass in the credentials to the WCF Service if I am not going to use some sort of login.  The way I want to do it is to have something like the following:

```
<GetColors>
    <Credentials>
        <UserName>test</<UserName>
        <Password>test</Password>
    </Credentials>
<GetColors>
```

GetColors would be the operation to be called and Credentials would be the credentials to access the service?

I have thought that the proper way to do this would be:

```
[OperationContract]
List<Color> GetColors(XDocument request);
```

Is the above the proper way to do this if I want to pass in the request to the client.  Also, if the root node is the operation, do I just have to read that and call the operation on the service or is there a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In such case the whole authentication is up to you. It is custom approach and either each operation or some [custom message inspector](http://weblogs.asp.net/paolopia/archive/2007/08/23/writing-a-wcf-message-inspector.aspx) (that means working with raw message) will have to check the message, search for credentials and validate them.

Comment: Assume the I had a copy of a xml file on my hard-drive that contained a valid xml request.  Would the same thing apply? Reading in the file and passing in the stream to the method?

Comment: You want to validate incoming request don't you? How does it relate to file on the disk? Client will send the message shown in your example and service must validate the client - it should be the first thing the service will do with the message.

Comment: I am looking into the custom message inspector now.

Comment: I actually followed this:  http://cgeers.com/2011/05/10/wcf-message-logging/ and it made it very clear to understand.

Comment: Do you have any recommendations on how to access elements like the soap action and how to insert headers such as a credentials header?